# No Ajax Request in Yii2 debug module

Tags: debugging, yii2

Yii2 comes with a great debug module.

Sadly, I can not view Ajax request. It seems that only standard request show up in the log.

I would expect that under `Requests/Last 10`, I could go back to an Ajax POST request.

Is there a way to do that?

=====
**Update**: The accepted answer is correct. But, it turned out that my problem was elsewhere. I was running the site from a testscript with url: `test.php/controller/action`

In that case, Yii2 ActiveForm includes an action `controller/action` in the form. **It omits the entry-script**. I wonder if this is a bug? Or is this intended behavior?

Of course, my debug modules is only attached via the test entry-script, and therefore missed recording the ajax POST request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the icon with label "Yii Debugger" at the left side of the debug toolbar.

`debug/default/index` - here you can view latest requests. Filter Ajax only if needed.

Defailed info about request is available after clicking on the tag.